# AWS Cognito: Receive sorted user list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm using Python with boto3 for accessing my AWS Cognito user data information.

###### Problem

I'm using [`list_users`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html?highlight=list_users_#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_users) to retrieve a paginated list of users to eventually show them in a web browser.
Problem is, the list is not sorted. So entries are difficult to find and every time I reload my Web UI a different order is shown.

How can I receive a **sorted** list of users.

In [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html?highlight=list_users_#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_users) I cannot find any information about sorting.

Comment: Have to ask why you don't sort them on your side? If I understood correctly, you always get the expected set of data based on the pagination, applying sort by name for example fixes your issue, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree with @ms12 . The docs you linked suggest that advanced filtering be done on the client side. You could consider using the [Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_RequestSyntax) functionality to bucket the responses into "users which start with A", "users which start with B", etc and then sort users within those subsets before serving them to your web app.

Comment: @ms12 The Paginated data is not sorted. I.e. the first set I receive might have a name "Bert" and "Markus", while the second set has name "Anton". So the sort would only apply to each page, not globally.

Comment: @dsillman2000 You're assuming I'm working on names written only in English letters. I'm working on a 10.000-letter alphabet. Making 10.000 requests for listing users seems impractical.